# LitElement does not update when attribute changed

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit, lit-html

I have very simple Lit component with an attribute.

I can change this attribute outside and Lit component receives new value and can display it, for example in the `<input>` tag.

This operation works as many times as I change the attribute. Problem occurs when I change the value manually in the `<input>`.

Component looks like this:

**cmp.ts**

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('cmp-tmp')
export class CmpTmp extends LitElement {
  
  @property({ type: Number })
  dt = 0;

  public render() {
    
    return html`
        <input value=${this.dt}>`;
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="module" src="./cmp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <cmp-tmp dt=""></cmp-tmp>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('cmp-tmp').setAttribute('dt', Date.now())">Set Date</button>
</body>
```

[Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gIDxjbXAtdG1wIGR0PVwiXCI-PC9jbXAtdG1wPlxuICA8YnV0dG9uIG9uY2xpY2s9XCJkb2N1bWVudC5xdWVyeVNlbGVjdG9yKCdjbXAtdG1wJykuc2V0QXR0cmlidXRlKCdkdCcsIERhdGUubm93KCkpXCI-U2V0IERhdGU8L2J1dHRvbj5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click "Set Date" button -> attrbiute was changed and input received new value
2. Click "Set Date" button -> attrbiute was changed and input received new value
3. Type something in the input field
4. Click "Set Date" button -> attrbiute was changed, new value was displayed in the console but input didn't received new timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody has the same issue: `.` should be used to bind value property.

i.e. `<input .value=${this.dt}>`

More details [here](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions)

Comment: To add, this happens specifically because of the way the `value` attribute works for `<input>` elements. The attribute controls the text field until user interaction changes that, after which the attribute has no effect and the property controls the text field, hence the `.` is required for the property binding.

Comment: If I could I'd upvote your answer 20 times. This "little" detail makes a huge difference when working with SELECT input types.